# Openshift container health probe connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

Hi openshift community,

I am currently migrating an app to Openshift and has encountered failed health probes due to connection refused. What I find strange is that if I ssh into the pod and use
curl localhost:10080/xxx-service/info
It returns HTTP 200 but if I use the IP address then it fails with

This is the details:

1. POD status

[image]

2. Logs in Openshift saying Spring boot started successfully

[image]

3. Openshift events saying probes failed due to connection refused

[image]

4. Tried SSH to pod to check using localhost which works

[image]

Not sure why the IP address is not resolving at the POD level.... Does anyone know the answer or have encountered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, it turns out it was Spring related.

It was a Spring Boot app that was being packaged as WAR file and deployed to Tomcat server. In the application.properties, it had this field:

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
```

Removing it has fixed this issue.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-server

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say in your case what exactly the issue is, as it is environment specific.

In general, you should **avoid using IP addresses when working with Kubernetes**, as these will change whenever a Pod is restarted (which may be the root cause for the issue you are seeing).

When defining readiness and liveness probes for your container, I would recommend that you always use the following syntax to define your checks (note that it does not specify the host):

```
...
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /xxx-service/info
    port: 10080
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 1
...
```

See also the Kubernetes or OpenShift documentation for more information:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/application_health.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request